# Is there something like "forced / induced electron-capture"?

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, radioactivity

I understand how electron-capture (also known as epsilon-decay) works and why it happens.

As far as I know we are able to do "induced fission", i.e. in nuclear reactors.

My question is: Is there a way to do (with our technology) something like "induced electron-capture"?

If so, how does it work? And if not, why isn't it possible?

I've been looking for an answer, but I couldn't find one on the internet.

Comment: did you consider to check the answer/vote/downvote/accept/ or ask more?

Answer (score 1):

The electron capture is an interesting kind of nuclear transformation. Rather more frequently you can find the opposite - a fully stripped atom decays by $\epsilon$-decay no more.

To enhance the decay, you - potentially - could modify an electron shells to increase the capture probability. Here is one claim with **ultrastrong magnetic field** e.g. http://cpl.iphy.ac.cn/fileup/PDF/2012-4-049701.pdf. Something like this has a potential for a processing of *a nuclear waste*, but the fields are crazy.

Another environment, where you can find heavily modified electron "orbits" is in **heavy stars**. There is high electron density with high electron energies and the electron can be captured by a nucleus from a continuum. And even (under normal conditions) stable nuclei can capture these high energy electrons

At even higher temperatures (>1GK), there can be a lot of $e^+ e^-$ pairs produced and even a positron can get captured by a nucleus.